# Git oddity with folders between branches

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I am working with git, still fairly new to working with branches, and I am coming across a real odd problem. I am not sure what is going on to be honest.

I am creating a git repo then adding a readme to it, and committing the changes.

```
git init
git touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'add readme'
```

From there I now have a master branch. I do:

```
git branch development
git checkout development
```

From there I have added 3 folders of files, since I am adding an old project to source control for the first time. The folders are:

```
Theme-arm 
FrontEnd 
ControlPanel
```

My goal is to add these files to the development branch and no other branches. I then do

```
git add *
git commit -m 'initial commmit'
```

That all works good. However When I switch back to master with

```
git checkout master
```

The problem, and what is leading to my confusion, is that ControlPanel and FrontEnd, but not theme-arm are now in master as well. I don't want them there, yet.

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding how git is working?

Comment: Why do you say they are in master?  The fact that they are in the working directory when you have checked out the master branch does not mean that they are tracked by master.  Try 'git status' and you will probably see them listed as untracked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check ControlPanel and FrontEnd for files that weren't put under version control when you did `git add *` in the development branch (you could just check what the contents of those directories are in your master branch).

Comment: To clarify: if you have untracked files (including ignored ones, perhaps build products), they will be left alone when switching branches. The fact that the files are there when you have the master branch checked out doesn't mean they're actually tracked on the master branch. Try `git show master:ControlPanel` to see what master is actually tracking there - and also simply `git status` to see if there are untracked files - you might see `ControlPanel/` under that section.

Comment: This has part of the answer, so I'll mark it as the answer and finish out my conclusion, which was an answer that got removed. Basically since there are not any files in the folders it is automatically not tracking them since git doesn't rack folders. If I had something in the folders then it would have tracked those files and the folders would have "disappeared". In the end it becomes a moot point as I merge the development branch into the master branch and those empty folders are there in both cases, I just can't tell the difference.